# How to observe the return value from a Repository class in a ViewModel?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines, android-mvvm

I have an android application using an MVVM architecture. On a button click, I launch a coroutine that calls a ViewModel method to make a network request. In my ViewModel, I have a LiveData observable for the return of that request, but I'm not seeing it update. It seems that my repository method isn't being called and I'm not sure why.

UI Click Listener

```
searchButton.setOnClickListener{
    CoroutineScope(IO).launch{
        viewModel.getUser(username.toString())
    }
}
```

ViewModel - Observables and invoked method

```
private var _user: MutableLiveData<User?> = MutableLiveData<User?>()
val user: LiveData <User?>
    get() = _user
...

suspend fun getUser(userId:String) {
   _user = liveData{
       emit(repository.getUser(userId))
   } as MutableLiveData<User?>
}
...
```

When I debug through, execution goes into the getUser method of the ViewModel but doesn't go into the **liveData** scope to update my _user MutableLiveData observable and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use `liveData` coroutine builder because the `getUser` is a suspended function and you are already calling it in a coroutine. Just post the result simply on `_user`.

```kotlin
suspend fun getUser(userId: String) {
    _user.postValue(repository.getUser(userId))
}
```

What you did on your code caused assigning a new instance of `LiveData` to `_user`, while the observer in the fragment is observing on previous `LiveData` which is instantiated by `private var _user: MutableLiveData<User?> = MutableLiveData<User?>()`. So, the update gets lost.

---

A better solution is to handle the creation of coroutines in your `ViewModel` class to keep track of them and prevent execution leak.

```kotlin
fun getUser(userId: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch(IO) {
        _user.postValue(repository.getUser(userId))
    }
}
```

And in the fragment:

```kotlin
searchButton.setOnClickListener{
    viewModel.getUser(username.toString())
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because your "MVVM structure" is not following the MVVM recommendations, nor the structured concurrency guidelines provided for coroutines.

```
    searchButton.setOnClickListener{
        CoroutineScope(IO).launch{ // <-- should be using a controlled scope
            viewModel.getUser(username.toString()) // <-- state belongs in the viewModel
        }
    }
```

Instead, it is supposed to look like this

```
searchButton.setOnClickListener {
    viewModel.onSearchButtonClicked()
}

username.doAfterTextChanged {
    viewModel.updateUsername(it)
}
```

And

```
class MyViewModel(
    private val application: Application,
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
): AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val repository = (application as CustomApplication).repository

    private val username = savedStateHandle.getLiveData("username", "")

    fun updateUsername(username: String) {
        username.value = username
    }
    
    val user: LiveData<User?> = username.switchMap { userId -> 
        liveData(viewModelScope + Dispatchers.IO) {
            emit(repository.getUser(userId))
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can do `user.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { user -> ... }` and it should work. If you really do need to fetch only when the button is clicked, you might want to replace the `liveData {` with a regular `suspend fun` call, calling from `viewModelScope.launch {`, and save the value to a LiveData.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. I didn't fully understand that the state should be encapsulated by the ViewModel in MVVM so this helps.